# How to get the list of all pages that i like on facebook and post on their wall

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

i have tried this

```
string accessToken = "MYTOKEN";
        FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
        var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        args["message"] = richTextBoxMessage.Text;           
        fbClient.Post("/PAGENAME/feed", args);
```

i have this error

> (OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the
>   application to perform this action

if i can post on the page wall by that code,so what is the permission name that i should add on the App settings.
And how can i get the names of all pages that i liked

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `fbClient.get("me/likes");` you can get all the pages that you have liked.

and the with `fbClient.Post("/PAGEID/feed", args);` you can post to page wall, provided your app has `publish_stream` permission from current user.

Comment: Hello Smita,
i get this (OAuthException - #2500) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

Comment: yes, you need to use a valid access token. Please make sure your access token is not expired. you can test the validity of the access token being used [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

Comment: ok it works, so how can i selct only the id of the page or the name?

Comment: with `me/likes?fields=id`, you will get only id of the pages. there are other fields `name`,`likes`,`can_post` , one or more of which you can add in fields parameter to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

The permission that your application should request for is the **publish_stream**

Please refer to the facebook developer docs for more information on permissions.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/